# Ruby link_to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller, link-to

If I have the below line in `app/views/schools/edit.html.erb`, does rails assume the *controller* is called `school_controller.rb`? How does it figure out which *controller* to look in?

```
link_to 'Check teachers', :action => :check_teachers, :id => @school.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to 'Check teachers', :action => :check_teachers, :id => @school.id
```

Rails pick it from "params[:controller]" which is 'school' for this one.

In case if you want different one you need to pass :controller option in the link_to

Answer (score 0):

you can pass controller in `link_to` tag like:

```
link_to 'Check teachers', :controller => "schools" :action => "check_teachers", :id => @school.id
```